# LibGDX need help to use viewport in box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, viewport

I got a problem in applying viewport to my project. The code below is trying to make a control panel to move a ball. However, when I try to use viewport, I have no idea how to do it. So I tried to follow the game from scratch method. I added the following code in the constructor.

```
  camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  viewport = new FitViewport(1280,720,camera);
  viewport.apply();

  camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
```

and I get nothing. There is nothing on the screen. I try to set camera position to different position and I just see nothing. What is the problem in my code?

```
public class GameScreen extends AbstractScreen {

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Viewport viewport;
private MyInputHandler handler;

//Box2D
World world;
Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
Body body;
Body control;
Fixture fixture;

//Parameters for controls
private double angle;
private double ControlMagnitudeX;
private double ControlMagnitudeY;
private float fControlMagnitudeX;
private float fControlMagnitudeY;


public GameScreen(final HunterLife game) {
    super(game);
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    camera.setToOrtho(false, HunterLife.V_WIDTH/PPM, HunterLife.V_HEIGHT/PPM);

    this.world = new World(new Vector2(0f, 0f), true);

    this.b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    handler = new MyInputHandler();

    BodyDef controlDef = new BodyDef();
    controlDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    controlDef.position.set(HunterLife.V_WIDTH/8/PPM, HunterLife.V_HEIGHT/5/PPM);
    this.control = world.createBody(controlDef);
    CircleShape controlCircle = new CircleShape();
    controlCircle.setRadius (0.1f);
    FixtureDef controlFixture = new FixtureDef();
    controlFixture.shape = controlCircle;
    controlFixture.isSensor = true;
    control.createFixture(controlFixture);


    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bdef.position.set(HunterLife.V_WIDTH/2/PPM,HunterLife.V_HEIGHT/2/PPM);
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    this.body = world.createBody(bdef);
    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius (0.05f);
    fdef.shape = circle;
    fdef.density = 1f;
    fdef.friction = 0f;
    fdef.restitution = 1f;
    fixture = body.createFixture(fdef);

    circle.dispose();
    controlCircle.dispose();

}


@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) - control.getPosition().y * PPM) * ((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) - control.getPosition().y * PPM) + ((Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) - control.getPosition().x * PPM) * ((Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) - control.getPosition().x * PPM) <= 0.25f * 0.25f * PPM * PPM) {

            angle = Math.abs(Math.atan(((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) - control.getPosition().y * PPM) / ((Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) - control.getPosition().x * PPM)));
            ControlMagnitudeX = 0.15f * Math.cos(angle);
            ControlMagnitudeY = 0.15f * Math.sin(angle);
            fControlMagnitudeX = MyInputHandler.getFloat(ControlMagnitudeX);
            fControlMagnitudeY = MyInputHandler.getFloat(ControlMagnitudeY);

            if ((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) >= control.getPosition().y * PPM && (Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) >= control.getPosition().x * PPM) {
                body.setLinearVelocity(fControlMagnitudeX, fControlMagnitudeY);
            }
            if ((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) < control.getPosition().y * PPM && (Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) >= control.getPosition().x * PPM) {
                body.setLinearVelocity(fControlMagnitudeX, -fControlMagnitudeY);
            }
            if ((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) >= control.getPosition().y * PPM && (Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) < control.getPosition().x * PPM) {
                body.setLinearVelocity(-fControlMagnitudeX, fControlMagnitudeY);
            }
            if ((HunterLife.V_HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY() * HunterLife.V_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) < control.getPosition().y * PPM && (Gdx.input.getX() * HunterLife.V_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) < control.getPosition().x * PPM) {
                body.setLinearVelocity(-fControlMagnitudeX, -fControlMagnitudeY);
            }
        }
        else {
            body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }
    }
    else {
        body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    }
    stage.act();
}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    game.sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.shapeBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();
    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}


@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}
}
```

Please ignore the stage thing.
The above code has no problem. Problem occurs when I add the viewport stuff.

Comment: What's the size of the camera when you don't have the viewport?

Comment: it is 1280 x 720 virtual size. In real device, it is the same as the resolution of the screen. but I am not sure what it is for different aspect ratio.

Comment: **Never** use pixel/meter conversion ratios. Use a camera and viewport with dimensions in meters (e.g. 16 by 9) and keep all of your bodies in meters. Cameras are here for a reason.

Comment: use StretchViewport instead of FitViewport when you want to use box2d in your game.

Comment: Is it because mixing up pixel unit and meter unit will make the body extremely small or extremely big?

Comment: @sunmaggot no it's not for pixel conversion. FitViewport keeps the aspect ratio by scaling the world up to fit the screen so it create problem when we integrate with box2d. secondly use small value in viewport because box2d work well in 1-10 meters.